# Selenium - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: b is null

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I am always getting this below exception while running my tests with Selenium Webdriver.

I have done some Googling but couldn't find anything related to this exception but found that this exception occurs when you are executing JavaScript in your code but I am NOT doing so.

Code throwing this exception:-

```
public void foo(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("www.xyz.com");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//iframe[contains(@id ,'easyXDM_default')])[2]")));
    WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//textarea[contains(@id,'ext-comp')])[1]"));
    .....

}
```

Exception is thrown whenever we are finding the textarea field in the application & the field is inside the frame.

Below is the stack trace:-

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: b is null
>
> Command duration or timeout: 21 milliseconds Build info: version:
>   '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time:
>   '2014-03-27 11:29:39' System info: host: 'HPDA0128', ip: '10.9.60.36',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_55' Session ID: f228cc09-2dd5-4658-9950-c504bf007b7f Driver
>   info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true,
>   takesScreenshot=true, version=30.0}]  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor13.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:445

How can I resolve this error or what does this error signify/mean?

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Where is the relevant code? What's on the line that has the error? Have you tried debeugging?

Comment: Yes, I have tried debugging by using try -catch block where I catch the exception & again performed the same action...but the results are the same

Comment: Could you please explain what does this exception mean.... i.e., what does "b" mean over here???

Comment: I dont see a `driver.get(url)` in the code you posted

Comment: Is this the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Did you try using a Thread.sleep before looking up for you textfield?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while trying to click on an element of my webpage.
I also tried to use coordinates but had the same error. *(Javascript error b is null)*

But it finally work by adding a refresh code line before trying to access and click to the element.

**Before:**

```
By myBy= By.xpath("//img[contains(@title,'title')]");
driver.findElement(myBy).click();
```

**After:**

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
By myBy= By.xpath("//img[contains(@title,'title')]");
driver.findElement(myBy).click();
```

Maybe you should try to refresh your page (*driver.navigate().refresh();*) before trying to access the element.